# How to make my jQuery plugin use the standard settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a jQuery plugin and I have some standard settings in my JS file.

I want people to change those settings in my HTML file. It's only working for a small part at the moment. I can already change the settings in my HTML file, but when I leave the settings in my HTML file blank it will stay blank.

Let's say I want an image to have a width of 100px. I type `imageWidth = "100px"` in my HTML and the `imageWidth` will actually be 100px. But when I leave `imageWidth = ;`  like this the `imageWidth` will be 0 because I didn't give it a width.

I want it so that my `imageWidth` will turn into my standard setting `imageWidth` if `imageWidth = "";`.

Here's my JS code in the HTML:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).jqueryPlugin({
        frontImage: "",
        backImage: "",
        imageHeight: "",
        imageWidth: ""
    }, {
        dialogHeight: "",
        dialogWidth: ""
    });
});
```

And here's part of my js code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.jqueryPlugin = function(optionsImage, optionsDialog) {
        var imageSettings = {
            frontImage: "http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/FRONT_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg",
            backImage: "http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg",
            imageHeight: "400px",
            imageWidth: "auto"
        };

        optionsImage = optionsImage || imageSettings.frontImage;

        var dialogSettings = {
            dialogHeight: "auto",
            dialogWidth: "auto"
        };

        if (optionsImage) {$.extend(imageSettings, optionsImage)}
        if (optionsDialog) {$.extend(dialogSettings, optionsDialog)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would advice against resetting empty strings in a setting object to default values. If someone sets an empty string as a setting, there may be good reasons to do that. Alternatively you could init your plugin like this

```
$(document).jqueryPlugin({
    frontImage: undefined,
    backImage: undefined,
    imageHeight: undefined,
    imageWidth: undefined
}, {
    dialogHeight: undefined,
    dialogWidth: undefined
});
```

... and all settings would be treated as default values.

If you insist in your approach of treating empty strings, you could use a function that converts each attribute of an object that is empty to `undefined`:

```
function empty2Undefined(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(idx) {
      if(!obj[idx]) obj[idx] = undefined;
    });   
}
```

And then, in your plugin:

```
empty2Undefined(optionsImage);
empty2Undefined(optionsDialog);
```

This works, because `undefined` is ignored by `$.extend`. From the jQuery docs:

> When two or more object arguments are supplied to $.extend(),
>   properties from all of the objects are added to the target object.
>   Arguments that are null or undefined are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wan to assign any option when you call plugin then don't need to mention as blank. use below code  . it will take default   imageHeight: "400px",  and   imageWidth: "auto" .

```
  $(function() {
    $(document).jqueryPlugin({
      frontImage: "http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/FRONT_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg",
       backImage: "http://www.c-and-a.com/iview/BACK_ZOOM2X/148243_1.jpg",
    }, {
      dialogHeight: "100px",
      dialogWidth: "100px"
    });
 });
```